# Haversine Formula prove inequality triangle

Tags: metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

I've been trying that distance using [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) is metric space. I can prove first and second conditon, but i have problem with prove that for haversine is true  that $ d(x,y)+d(y,z)>= d(x,z) $

I am stuck, I have continued on different paths and they all seem to give nothing, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume we have a sphere $\,S\,$ and measure distances
between points $\,x\,$ and $\,y\,$ on $\,S\,$ using the 
angle they subtend when viewed from the center of $\,S\,$.
That is, we denote this angle by $\,d(x,y).\,$ The
great-circle distance is $\,d(x,y)\,$ multiplied by the
radius of $\,S\,$. Given points $\,x,y,z\,$ on $\,S\,$
forming a spherical triangle define the side angles by
$$ a:=d(x,y),\; b:=d(y,z),\; c:=d(x,z).$$
Denote the angle of the spherical triangle at $\,y\,$ by
$\,C.\,$

The spherical law of cosines, the cosine addition
theorem, and using haversines gives the equation
$$ \text{hav}(a+b) = \text{hav}(c) + \sin(a)\sin(b)
\cos(C/2)^2. $$ The haversine function is strictly
monotone increasing on the interval $\,[0,\pi],\,$
and the sines of the sides are positive. This then
implies that $\,c \le a+b\,$ which is the triangle
inequality for spherical triangles.

**EDIT:** Compare this with the Wikipedia article
[Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).